# UncategorizedKeyValueException trying to save RedisHash via repository with transaction support

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-redis

**Problem:**

After enabling transaction support (`redisTemplate.setEnableTransactionSupport(true)`)
I get `UncategorizedKeyValueException` trying to save `@RedisHash` in repository.

Everything works fine when transaction support is disabled.

Direct operations via `RedisTemplate` work fine with transaction support.

**Stacktrace:**

```
...
at org.lorem.LoremController.create(TestController.java:41)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisKeyValueAdapter.lambda$put$0(RedisKeyValueAdapter.java:236)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:224)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:184)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:171)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisKeyValueAdapter.put(RedisKeyValueAdapter.java:231)
at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.lambda$insert$0(KeyValueTemplate.java:165)
at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.execute(KeyValueTemplate.java:343)
... 56 more
```

**Background:**

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-data-redis:2.0.4.RELEASE`

Configuration:

```
@Bean
@Primary
StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
    StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate = new StringRedisTemplate();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
    redisTemplate.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
    redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();

    return redisTemplate;
}
```

RedisHash:

```
@RedisHash("test")
public class Test {
    private String id;
    private String field;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface TestRepository extends CrudRepository<Test, String> {
}
```

Thanks :)

**Update:**

Things break at the following line in `RedisKeyValueAdapter`:

```
boolean isNew = connection.del(objectKey) == 0;
```

`del()` returns null since it runs in a transaction. Doesn't repositories suppose to work with transaction support enabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redis Repositories do not work with Redis transactions. This is explained here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-862

> Redis Repositories do not work with Redis transactions as operations that change the underlying data are queued and executed at the end of the transaction. These commands return null. However, we require the outcome immediately at invocation time.

Comment: Even though the link explains your answer, you should include a summary.